# Old (1-2 years) photos on iPhone appear blurry, but iCloud Photos are not turned on

Tags: photos.app

I see this question asked a lot and the answer is always to turn off "Optimize phone storage" in iCloud's photo stream settings. My photos aren't backed up to iCloud though so this isn't a problem. The exclamation symbol isn't there either. All the pictures are just blurry and the videos won't load. What's going on here?

Comment: Plug it in and try reboot. If possible, make a backup first.